# How can I create a macro to compile a CoffeeScript file I am editing from inside VIM?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I am writing a lot of [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) in VIM and I compile it very frequently by typing `: coffee -c %`. How can I easily create a macro so I don’t need to keep typing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at (with the single quotes typed):

```
:help 'makeprg'
```

For example, try this:

```
:set makeprg=coffee\ -c\ %
```

Then you can just type `:make` instead.

Comment: When I try that I get "E518: Unknown option: -c"

Comment: That's my fault. I forgot to escape the spaces. I revised my answer.

Comment: Awesome man, thanks a lot! I was fooling around with Unix aliases forever and it turned out the answer was way more simple than I thought. This works great. Thanks again!